# jls7 generic inner class documentation error

Tags: java, generics, documentation, inner-classes

```
class Jls7error<T extends OutputStream> {
    class Jls7errorInner<S extends T> {
        public S out;
    }
}
```

According to jls7 Oracle documentation, this code should not compile:

> It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic class C anywhere in
>     
> ...
>  
>  • any class nested within C.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2
 
(pag 185, docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) 
In fact, this code does compile and run on my jdk 1.7
Is it a documentation error?

EDIT:
It was a documentation error in the PDF version. 
Oracle corrected the documentation in html and pdf documentation.

Comment: For future reference, there's an [HTML version of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) which will allow you to link directly to the [section you are talking about](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2).

Comment: I don't understand; I don't see the bullet point you're quoting.

Comment: documentation tell me: "you cannot reference type parameter T of class Jls7error in the inner class Jls7errorInner", nevertheless the code does compile without error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you're seeing `any class nested within C`. That section actually says

> It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic
>   class C anywhere in:
>
> - the declaration of a static member of C (§8.3.1.1, §8.4.3.2, §8.5.1),    or
> - the declaration of a static member of any type declaration nested    within C, or
> - a static initializer of C (§8.7), or
> - a static initializer of any class declaration nested within C.

Here's an example to demonstrate what each bullet is disallowing:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private static T t; // first bullet makes this a compiler error

    static {
        T t; // third bullet makes this a compiler error
    }

    private static class Bar {
        private static T t; // second bullet makes this a compiler error

        static {
            T t; // fourth bullet makes this a compiler error
        }
    }

    private class Baz {
        private static T t; // second bullet again

        // you can't have a static initializer
        // in a non-static nested class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Moved to answer for space/formatting.)

The only place that references this states:

> It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic class C anywhere in:
>
> - the declaration of a static member of C (§8.3.1.1, §8.4.3.2, §8.5.1), or
> - the declaration of a static member of any type declaration nested within C, or
> - a static initializer of C (§8.7), or
> - a static initializer of any class declaration nested within C.

Comment: New version of pdf is already correct. Is it possible to delete this post?

Comment: @RobertoMereghetti I see the exact same text in the PDF you linked to as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had a previous version of the same pdf, they have already correct the documentation. Is it possible to delete this post?

Comment: @RobertoMereghetti There is no way to delete questions after answers have been posted, but you are allowed to answer your own question.